# How to capture frame from a video?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-videoview

I want to capture frames from a playing video. I have tried `MediaMetadataRetriever` & it works fine for local videos (kept in SD card & in res-raw directory). But in my app I am playing videos from web so it doesn't work, in that case.

In my app, I am playing videos of Vimeo & YouTube. For playing YouTube video, I am using `YouTubePlayerView` & Vimeo's video I am playing in [VideoEnabledWebView](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView).

I am not able to capture the frame from both these views.

I have tried [android-screenshot-lib](https://github.com/rtyley/android-screenshot-lib) but it's not doing what I am looking for.

I am trying hard to get any solutions, but no luck so far...please give me some way to solving my issue.

Comment: so you just want the thumbnails of the video ?

Comment: No thumbnail, it should capture from a playing video.